Getting a 400 error when calling Google Vertex API with "retrieval" function (datastore)
I'm getting the below error whenever I include the retrieval tool in an API request. To confirm, the call works fine without adding in a retrieval tool.
I'm POSTing to this endpoint:
https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%5C%5C\<project_id\>/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/gemini-1.0-pro-001:generateContent

And this payload:
{
  "contents": [{
    "role": "user",
    "parts": [{
      "text": <prompt>
    }]
  }],
  "model": "projects/<project_id>/locations/us/publishers/google/models/gemini-1.0-pro-001"
}

Works fine, but adding in this to the payload:
  "tools": [{
    "retrieval": {
      "vertexAiSearch": {
        "datastore": "projects/<project_id>/locations/us/collections/default_collection/dataStores/<datastore_id>"
      }
    }
  }]

Causes the 400 error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

Things suggested in other Stack Overflow threads that haven't helped:

ensure the app and the bucket are the same location (they are)

ensure there's sufficient permissions (and wait for any permissions changes to take effect) (permI've read all the answers I can find about this issue but none of them helped me.

ensure the app and the bucket are the same location (they are)

ensure there's sufficient permissions (and wait for any permissions changes to take effect) (permissions are fine)

ensure Enterprise is activated (I ensured it was checked when creating the datastore)

ensure there's a search app created that links to the cloud storage (bucket) - I did this however a search app is completely separate to the agent app (I don't see how there's any link between the two) so I'm sure it doesn't help, but anyway.


And just to confirm (as it may help others), the hierarchy of objects in Vertex is this:

Endpoint - The location in the URL must be a specific location (eg; us-central1), or "global", but can't be a larger region (eg; "us") - I selected "us-central1"
Project (simply a container for everything else) - Projects don't have locations.
App (Can be agent, search, or chat) - You can select a specific region (eg; us-central1) or a larger region (us). I chose "us".
Data stores (Kinda of links the App to data - Data can be website, cloud storage, API, etc) - I chose "cloud storage".
Cloud Storage (the actual data) - You can only select a larger area (eg; us) on a bucket - So I selected "us".

Logs show that the bucket is indexed just fine, I can ask the model about the one test document I uploaded (using Workbench) and it works fine.
I've tried setting all different types of locations. No joy.
I know the Agent is connecting just fine to the Cloud Storage because if there's any permissions issue it doesn't let you save your selections.
I've stuck with gemini-1.0-pro-001 (not gemini-1.0-pro-002) across the board because the gemini-1.0-pro-002 is not an option in the Agent. I didn't want model clashes.
I can't think of what else to check.

To ground your models to your source data, you need to have prepared and saved your data to Vertex AI Search. To do this, you need to create a data store in Vertex AI Agent Builder.
If you are starting from scratch, you need to prepare your data for ingestion into Vertex AI Agent Builder. See Prepare data for ingesting to get started. Depending on the size of your data, ingestion can take several minutes to several hours. Only unstructured data stores are supported for grounding.
After you've prepared your data for ingestion, you can Create a search data store. After you've successfully created a data store, Create a search app to link to it and Turn Enterprise edition on.
Here is an example on how to ground the gemini 1.5 Flash model. Use the following instructions to ground a model with your own data. But before proceeding, There are prerequisites needed before you can ground model output to your data.

I can't add screen shots but in my OP I outlined everything I had done, which is everything you are suggesting to do.
I have an agent, a "retrieval" tool attached, a linked datastore (unstructured documents), which in turn links to the cloud bucket with documents in it. It even shows it's "processed" the documents.
I've done everything as per the documentation, there's no errors, but it just refuses an API request when I add in a retrieval tool into the JSON payload.
